# Predicate gives list of unbound variables instead of all possible lists

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

Let's say I have a list L1 = [1,2,3], I want to write a predicate that can find all permutations of this list i.e

```
[1,2,3]
[1,3,2]
[2,1,3]
[2,3,1]
[3,1,2]
[3,2,1]
```

Note: I know `permutation(L1, L2).` does exactly this, but I want to write my own predicate that does this for an exercise.

I'm a prolog rookie, so I thought lets first make a predicate that returns `true`when two lists L1 and L2 are permutations of eachother. The requirements for that are:

1. They need to be the same length
2. Every element in L1 has to be in L2

So I came up with this:

```
permute(L1,L2):-
    forall(member(X,L1), member(X,L2)), % every element that is a member in L1 has to be a member in L2
    length(L1,A), % the length of the list L1 is A
    length(L2,A). % AND the length of the list L2 is A
```

So when I query `permute([1,2,3], [1,3,2]).`I do get `true` as expected, and `permute([1,2,3], [1,3]).` and `permute([1,2,3], [1,3,4]).` both give false. So my predicate works to see if 2 lists are permutations of eachother.

But if I ask: `permute([1,2,3], A).` I want to be able to see all valid A, i.e all permutations of [1,2,3]. Instead I get unbounded variables.
Something like `A = [_942, _948, _954].`

Why does this happen, why can't i look through all possible lists A? Is there a simple way to modify my code to make that happen?

Comment: The problem is that you're approaching this iwhere `L` is `L1` with `mperatively like a C program. Try defining `permutation` as a relationship between the lists, and think recursively. `permutation([], []).` is true in the base case. Then you could have another rule that defines the permutation of a list `L` in terms of `L1` that has an element removed `L`. So `P` is a permutation of `L` if I remove `X` from `L` giving `L1`, `P1` is a permutation of `L1`, and then I insert `X` anywhere into `P1` giving `P`. If you search this site for `[prolog] permutation` there should be lots of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your two points definition is wrong. According to it, `permute( [1,1,2], [1,2,2])` should hold (and it does).

The *"simple"* way is to use `select/3`,

```erlang
select( [A|B], X):- select(A, X, Y), select(B, Y).
select( [], []).
```

And it works, but only in one direction. Even adding (simple) `same_length` doesn't help:

```erlang
permute( A, B):- same_length( A, B), select( B, A).

same_length( A, B):- length(A, N), length(B, N).   % wrong

% permute( [1,2,3], X).    % OK
% permute( X, [1,2,3]).    % doesn't terminate after the last solution
```

No, `same_length/2` must be defined carefully, as

```erlang
same_length( [], []).
same_length( [_|A], [_|B]):- same_length(A, B).
```

*Then* `permute` is OK in *both* directions.